# VPN / Lan routing table Windows 7

Tags: vpn, routing

I am currently  having trouble setting up a vpn connection. I am willing to get all the trafic related to the vpn through the vpn and al the other traffic (lan related & internet) through the normal lan conection.

My network looks like this:

- 192.168.1.0 - my local LAN
- 192.168.1.1 - my router
- 192.168.1.2 - my computer
- 192.168.5.0 - VPN network
- 192.168.5.254 -VPN gateway
- 78.192.abc.xy - my vpn server

Here is how my route is set up : route print

```
===========================================================================

Interface List
 14...00 ff 9c 77 1b 09 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 10...00 1e 8c 2d 78 bb ......Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Carte Microsoft ISATAP
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     30
    78.192.abc.xy  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     30
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
      192.168.5.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.5.254     192.168.5.25     21
     192.168.5.25  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.5.25    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.5.25    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.5.25    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      192.168.0.0  255.255.255.255    192.168.27.65       2
    78.192.abc.xy  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      10
===========================================================================
```

when tracert 192.168.5.30 I see that it still use 192.168.1.1 (my lan) in order to try and get it.
Can anyone please help me with those routes ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly got it working

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     21
    78.192.abc.xy  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
      192.168.5.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.5.5    276
      192.168.5.5  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.5.5    276
    192.168.5.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.5.5    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.5.5    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.5.5    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
    78.192.abc.xy  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1       1
===========================================================================
```

Comment: What was the problem?  How did you fix it?   

Without that information, this question/answer may as well be deleted.

With that information, this question/answer may help others.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: I am not an expert. I  have tried to get it working with no luck firstly. and then came down to a configuration that works. Basicly, I guess that there is no need to use gateways for the VLAN to work - onlink does the job. 
All the magic was to reset back to default config and to delete the internet route added by the VLAN:

    0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.5.254      192.168.5.5     21